# Object is possibly 'undefined' although I checked in if

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<{ [key in PROJECT_ROLE]?: number[] } | null>(null);
```

`data` is an object with some key in `PROJECT_ROLE`

This is `PROJECT_ROLE`:

```
export enum PROJECT_ROLE {
  OWNER = "OWNER",
  SUPERVISOR = "SUPERVISOR",
  QA = "QA",
  LAST_CHECK = "LAST_CHECK",
  CHECKER = "CHECKER",
  ENTRY = "ENTRY",
  MEMBER = "MEMBER",
}
```

I have an handle:

```
const handle = (index: number, role: PROJECT_ROLE) => {
  if (data && data[role]) {
    const id = data[role].indexOf(index);
  }
};
```

and I got:

[image]

Why? I checked it in `if` but it still show `error`.

And how can I fixed that?

Answer (score 1):

Type guarding property doesn't change the type of the parent. There is an open GitHub issue [ms/TS/42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) about it.

Meanwhile, this can be fixed by the following approaches:

If you disable `strictNullChecks` tsconfig option it there will be no error as shown in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwAoCUDyApAUQGEAVAfVwBkC4BvAKDjhwHUA5ArOAXjgHJWHLHwA0jOAGUAqhk4A1AJIScXXn2mysi5cLFMAigEEe-I6PGVDE8kQASxANIm+l62TuPzTD0QednPn664gRsJFgAms6h4RFecACyBAkAQv5qSamc5gC+9PQAxhCIAM7wACYAhjCVAFx0cADaANbAAJ5wAJaImLiEpBQ41AC6APz1KKgARsBQjcNwOXAAPnAoADbrJrQ5ANz5RaXwABaViOXrwCYAFN3loBNoM1AicFAQl-XY+MTkVAQASh4AD46OJOgAzODXKo1OAAMnhcFhlUa70uwyBDCYTEOZS65RMKLRH2AwwAdHdQDgIbdzqAAfsmHk9vQgA)

An alternative solution would be to use *optional chaining* and store `data[role]` in a separate variable then check that variable in the `if`:

```
const handle = (index: number, role: PROJECT_ROLE) => {
  const item = data?.[role]
  if (item) {
    const id = item.indexOf(index);
  }
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwAoCUDyApAUQGEAVAfVwBkC4BvAKDjhwHUA5ArOAXjgHJWHLHwA0jOAGUAqhk4A1AJIScXXn2mysi5cLFMAigEEe-I6PGVDE8kQASxANIm+l62TuPzTD0QednPn664gRsJFgAms6h4RFecACyBAkAQv5qSamc5gC+9PQAxhCIAM7wACYAhjCVAFx0cADaANbAAJ5wAJaImLiEpBQ41AC6APz1KKgARsBQjcNwOXAAPnAoADbrJrQ5ANz5RaXwABaViOXrwCYAFN3loBNoM1AicFAQl-XY+MTkVAQASh4AD46OJDmUujBgOheFUaqMAHSNd6XYbiToAMzgt2hqCBDCYTAh8E65RMnTxiLuoBwmNu51AAP2TDye3oQA)

Comment: I doubt if suggesting to disable `strictNullChecks` is a good idea...

Comment: I'm not encouraging to do any of the suggested approaches, I just present the reason and solutions to it

Comment: Yet still your answer doesn't cover the main issue that is why `data[role]` is possibly _undefined_ even if OP used the condition to secure it?

Comment: The first sentence is the explanation of it. When the option is disabled the compiler doesn't check this

Comment: If so, then why in following case ts does not throw any errors? `const abc: string[] | undefined = []; 
if (abc) {
    abc.length;
}`

Comment: got your point. updated the answer

Comment: Oh noes. This is bad. But makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the ? operator in the state initialisation

```js
  const [data, setData] = useState<{ [key in PROJECT_ROLE]: number[] } | null>(null);
```

This will fix the TS error message